# Problem related to adiabatic invariants

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, string, adiabatic

> A simple pendulum is oscillating in the gravity field, while its length slowly decreases with time. Determine amplitude of the small oscillations $A$ of the bob, when length of the oscillating part of the string would be reduced by a half. Initial amplitude of the bob is $A_0$.

What approach should I use?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry.. another problem was in my mind and by mistake I mixed them up. I will edit it

Answer (score 1):

This question is a bit confusing since the amplitude does not depend on the oscillations, it's just the length of the pendulum. So either you calculate the rate of change $\frac{dA}{dt}$ or you're dealing with a damped system

But assuming you meant damping then I would suggest you find the damping factor
$$x(t) = A_{\circ}e^{-\gamma t}cos(\omega t) $$
Where $\gamma$ is the damping factor.
This will give you the change in amplitude with time